# FFmpeg : Desktop Recording for YouTube

Tags: video, ffmpeg, youtube, recording

I was reading YouTube Help [Recommended upload encoding settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) page, and I found this command from a site [Youtube recommended encoding settings for FFmpeg](https://scribbleghost.net/2018/10/26/youtube-recommended-encoding-settings-for-ffmpeg/).

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -f dshow \
  -i audio="Microphone (2- Realtek Audio)" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 \
  -profile:v high -level 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p -bf 2 -coder 1 -b:v 15M -c:a aac \
  -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 384k output.mp4
```

I modified the command to capture my desktop and microphone, but I was wondering if this is the best quality I can get or whether there are any improvements I can make. My goal is to get the best quality for a 1080p60 video.

Comment: @MarianD, note that by breaking lines using ```\``` you made this command linux (and mac) only, when there was no any information about OS and it's possible that the question is about windows.

Comment: @Qwertiy, you're right, I'm aware of it, but by scrolling the long line disappears the big picture (and the answerers' will for answering such a question). So I decided to use the POSIX continuation symbol `\ ` (except questions with `windows` tag) — for FFmpeg users it is “lingua franca”, well-known to Windows' users, too, which have no problem to translate it to the `^` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

- `-profile:v high -level 4.0` - You don't need to set a profile or level because you're not targeting any specific, limited, or outdated devices. These options don't matter because YouTube is going to re-encode whatever you give it and set its own profile and level.
- `-pix_fmt yuv420p` - You can let YouTube deal with the pixel format.
- `-bf 2 -coder 1` - These are already handled automatically by `-preset`.
- `-b:v 15M` - This is mutually exclusive with `-crf`. Just use `-crf` instead. It will let you set the quality instead of you trying to apply an arbitrary bitrate.
- `-ar 48000 -ac 2` - No need to change the audio rate or channel layout. If you do what to change those do it via the [dshow](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) `-sample_rate` and `-channels` input options.

So your command can look like:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (2- Realtek Audio)" -c:v libx264rgb -preset slow -crf 18 -b:a 384k output.mp4
```

- The input is RGB, so you can avoid the RGB to YUV conversion by using `-c:v libx264rgb`.
- If your computer can handle it then consider using a slower `-preset`.
- You can use flac or libopus for audio (change `output.mp4` to `output.mkv`), but for microphone it will hardly matter.
- You can try `-crf 17` if you think you can see a difference. I wouldn't bother with the huge file increase from using lossless (`-crf 0`).
- You can see if dshow is faster than gdigrab for [capturing the desktop](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#Windows). I don't use Windows so I can't test for you.

Note that a non-FFmpeg based player may not be able to decode the file, but I'm fairly certain YouTube will have no issues with it.